# iphone cocos2d v2.0.0-rc0 - can't disable touch

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, touch

I've been trying to resolve a problem for a long time, unfortunately i couldn't find a solution. I hope you can help me...

I'm trying to develop a turn based game. Player 1 is the user, player 2 is the iphone. I want to receive touches when it's the player1's turn.

```
-(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
if (self.playerNo==1) {   //control player1
CGPoint touchLocation = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];
[self selectSpriteForTouch:touchLocation];
return YES;
}
//if it's not player1's turn, return NO
return NO;
}
```

When it's iphones turn, I want to disable touches during 5 seconds. I tried all the ways below, but no success.

```
-(void)iphonesTurn
{

[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5];

//
//game logic...
//

}
```

During 5 seconds I touch screen several times. I realised that all the touches looks like stored and the app reacts to all of my touches when it's the player1's turn.

How can I completely disable touches?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;`

Comment: unfortunately the same thing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where is located your snippet of code but if it runs into the main thread you must NEVER block (pause) it!

Try to do something like that (it works with the final version of cocos2d 2.0):

```
- (void)iphonesTurn
{
   [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] touchDispatcher] setDispatchEvents:NO];
   [self scheduleOnce:@selector(enableTouch) delay:5.0f];
}

- (void)enableTouch
{
   [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] touchDispatcher] setDispatchEvents:YES];
}
```

Comment: Cool, glad to hear that. Just think to mask the question as resolved. ;)